# Char comparison isn't working

Tags: java, char

I am trying to create a file reader. the reader will return an array of  objects. however, the [if (a == ' ');] statement always passes as true. In the file that the program reads, the first character is 'P' but the if statement still returns true.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class MyFileReader
    {
        Contact class1 = new Contact();

        public ArrayList<Contact> read(File file) throws IOException
        {
            ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            int x = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int start = 0;
            int end;
            int count = 1;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                while (i < line.length())
                {
                    char a = line.charAt(i);
                    if (a == ' ');
                    {
                        end = i;
                        System.out.println(count);
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            class1.setFirstName(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            //System.out.println(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            start = end;
                            count++;
                        }
                        else if (count == 2)
                        {
                            class1.setLastName(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            //System.out.println(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            start = end;
                            count++;
                        }
                        else if (count == 3)
                        {
                            class1.setPhone(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            //System.out.println(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            start = end;
                            count++;
                        }
                        else if (count == 4)
                        {
                            class1.setEmail(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            //System.out.println(line.substring(start, end + 1));
                            start = end;
                            count++;
                            list.add(class1);

                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                    class1 = new Contact();
                    x++;
                    count++;
                }
                x = 0;
                count = 0;
            }

            br.close();
            return list; // returns the array
        }


    }
```

Comment: `if` with semicolon after it `if (condition);` is the same as `if` with empty block `if (condition){}`. So everything after such `if(conditon); System.out.println("FREEEDOOOOM");` is not related to its condition.

Answer (score 6):

remove the semicolon. `if (a == ' ')`.

Also suggest you delete the question since it's just a typo.

Comment: I doubt that deleting question by OP will be possible since there is already upvoted answer :)